# Why is the server response incorrect when the request is read correctly?

Tags: javascript, express, npm, nodemon

I'm on the Node.js repl, I created a new project folder and initialized the NPM, then I installed the Express package and wrote the following code into the js file:

```
 const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    app.listen(5000, function(){
        console.log("server started on port 5000");
    })

    app.get("/", function(req, res){
        res.send("Hi There! Welcome!")
    })

    app.get("/speak/:animalName", function(req,res){
        var animalName = req.params.animalName;
        var verso = "verso";
        if (animalName = "pig"){
            verso = "oink"
        } else if (animalName = "dog"){
            verso = "bau"
        } else if (animalName = "cat"){
            verso = "Miao"
        }

        console.log(req.params);
        res.send("THE " + animalName + " says " + verso);
    })

    app.get("*", function (req, res){
        res.send("Sorry, the page cannot be found")
    })
```

When I open the js file with Nodemon the server starts correctly and when I type a specific pattern in the URL field the console.log returns me the req.params correctly (in the example below: for I typed "cat" the console returned `{ animalName: 'cat' }`
Nonetheless, the response in the browser is not the correct one:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You're using a single `=` in your conditions. This always assigns the variable, instead of testing for equality. Use `==` or `===`.

Comment: Can't count the number of hours I've lost because of that. And then you end up with tunnel vision. It isn't until someone else points it out that you notice it.